# La funcion form.is_valid() no funciona en Django

Tags: python, django, formularios

espero puedan ayudarme de antemano  muchas gracias, resulta que cuento con un formulario que necesito llenar con información de mi base de datos antes de mandarlo al template, pero resulta que cuando quiero evaluarlo mediante el metodo POST, al momento de validarlo con if form.is_valid(): me retorna un False y no se por que, como podría solucionarlo, a continuación mi código.

```
class CheckboxForm(forms.Form):
    check_0 = forms.BooleanField(label="", required=False)
    check_1 = forms.BooleanField(label="", required=False)
    check_2 = forms.BooleanField(label="", required=False)
    check_3 = forms.BooleanField(label="", required=False)
    check_4 = forms.BooleanField(label="", required=False)
    check_5 = forms.BooleanField(label="", required=False)
    check_6 = forms.BooleanField(label="", required=False)
    check_7 = forms.BooleanField(label="", required=False)
    check_8 = forms.BooleanField(label="", required=False)
    check_9 = forms.BooleanField(label="", required=False)
    check_10 = forms.BooleanField(label="", required=False)
    check_11 = forms.BooleanField(label="", required=False)
    check_12 = forms.BooleanField(label="", required=False)
    check_13 = forms.BooleanField(label="", required=False)
    check_14 = forms.BooleanField(label="", required=False)

    def __init__(self, school=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CheckboxForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if school:
            print("entro")
            values = InstitucionalValues.objects.all()
            i = 0
            for value in values:
                name = "check_" + str(i)
                v_school = value.school.all()
                for v in v_school:
                    if v == school:
                        self.fields[name] = forms.BooleanField(label="", required=False, initial=True)
                        break
                i = i + 1
```

Y el metodo post:

```
class VistaFormulario(View):
    def post(self, request):
       form = CheckboxForm(request.POST)
       if form.is_valid():
```

Comment: Añade un `form.is_valid(); print(form.errors)` antes de tu sentencia `if form.is_valid()`, ¿qué te sale?

Comment: Hola Cesár si, ya intente imprimir el form.errors, pero no me arroja nada.

Answer (score 1):

Un ejemplo muy sencillo de como hacerlo con Class usando FormView

Mi ModelForm

```
from django import forms

class PostsForms(forms.ModelForm):

    titulo = forms.CharField(max_length=240, min_length=8, required=True,
                             widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
                                 'class': 'form-control',
                                 'name': 'titulo', 'id': 'titulo', 'placeholder': 'Escribe un titulo'}))
    cuerpo = forms.CharField(required=True,
                             widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={
                                 'class': 'form-control',
                                 'name': 'cuerpo',
                                 'id': 'cuerpo',
                                 'placeholder': 'Contenido del posts'}))
    categoria = forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
    tags = forms.CharField(max_length=240, min_length=10, required=True,
                           widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control',
                                 'placeholder': 'Etiquetas separadas por comas (,)', 'id': 'tags'}))
    img_file = forms.CharField(required=True,
                               widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
                                   'class': 'form-control',
                                   'placeholder': 'Seleccion un archivo',
                                   'id': 'append-big-btn',
                                   'readonly': '',

                               }))
    permitir_comentarios = forms.BooleanField(required=False,
                                              widget=forms.CheckboxInput(
                                                  attrs={}))

    class Meta:
        model = posts
        fields = {'titulo', 'categoria', 'cuerpo', 'tags', 'permitir_comentarios', 'img_file'}
        widgets = {
            'categoria': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
        }
```

y mi vista  FormView

```
class CreatePosts(FormView):
    categoria = categorias.objects.all()
    model = posts
    template_name = "posts/create_form.html"
    form_class = PostsForms

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = form
        return self.render_to_response(context)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form, **kwargs)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form, **kwargs)

    def form_invalid(self, form, **kwargs):
        context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = form

        return self.render_to_response(context)

    def form_valid(self, form, **kwargs):
        context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = form
        add = form.save(commit=False)
        add.user = self.request.user
        add.img_file = self.request.POST['upload_file']
        add.save()
        form.save_m2m()

        haySeguidores = Seguidores.follow_to_user(2, str(add.pk), int(self.request.user.pk) ,1) #Prueba de notificaciones
        for follows in haySeguidores['user_follows']:
            notis = Notificaciones()
            #print(follows.seguidor_id)

            notis.user = follows.seguidor_id
            notis.tipo = 1
            notis.tipo_id = add.pk
            notis.user_for = self.request.user.pk
            notis.type_for = 0
            notis.save()



        redirect_url = reverse('ver-posts', args=[str(add.pk), slugify(self.request.POST['titulo'])])
        return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_url)

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(CreatePosts, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

Espero te sirva de ayuda.

Comment: Hola vdjkelly, Si voy a intentarlo , espero me sirva en un momento contesto